# References for Smale's Geometry

Tags: reference-request, symplectic-geometry

I read that Smale recast classical mechanics in terms of symplectic geometry. I know a bit about classical mechanics but nothing about symplectic geometry.

Are there any writings from Smale on this which I could read?

And also what other books or texts are there which cover this?

Thank you!

Comment: My understanding is that this goes back before Smale; more precisely, the Hamilton--Jacobi formulation of classical mechanics in terms of canonical coordinates is (I believe) the original inspiration for symplectic geometry.  (The phase space in classical mechanics is naturally a symplectic manifold.)  If you do a Google search for "geometry and physics text" you find many references discussing this material.  Probably others will leave specific suggestions here.

Comment: I'm also trying to learn more about this area. A basic book that gives wonderful intuition is Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*. I've also seen Marsden & Ratiu's *Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry* mentioned but haven't read it myself.

Comment: Smale's name is associated more with (classical) dynamical systems than classical mechanics per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend Foundations of Mechanics by Abraham and Marsden. It's a huge book, with a very rigorous treatment of mechanics. Altough Smale is not an author, he's heavily cited in the book (by the way, the book provides an *excellent* bibliography).